# Why RestKit 0.20 RKMappingResult have fields with "_" marks?

Tags: restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a strange response from Restkit 0.20:

Response from my server:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Date: Fri, 22 Nov 2013 01:55:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

17
{"returnedParam1":1000}
0
```

Response class:

```
@interface RSReturnModel : NSObject

@property(assign,nonatomic) NSString *param1;
@property(assign,nonatomic) NSString *param2;
@property(assign,nonatomic) NSString *param3;
@end
```

ResponseMapping and `RKRequest`:

```
 RKObjectMapping *returnedObjectMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[RSReturnModel class]];
    [returnedObjectMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
     @"returnedParam1" : @"param1",
     @"returnedParam2" : @"param2"
     }];
   RKResponseDescriptor *responseDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:returnedObjectMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
```

MappingResult from success block:

```
RSReturnModel *res = [mappingResult firstObject];
  res   RSReturnModel * 0x094ded70
     NSObject   NSObject    
        _param1 NSString *  0x43000002
        _param2 NSString *  0x00000000
        _param3 NSString *  0x000398e0
```

So, any parser's error but `RSResultModel` has fields as "_param1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have used automatic property synthesising (i.e., you haven't explicitly used `@synthesize`), `_param1` is the instance variable name for the `param1` property. So the log is simply showing you the actual 'memory' name, not the property name you're familiar with.

There don't appear to be any issues with your RestKit configuration or the result.

Comment: Wain,you are correct,but my problem was no have correct result value from "_param1".Now,I see what is the problem:typing - json is "{"returnedParam1":1000}", value is as NSNumber and objC class as "NSString *param1".Anyway - thank for your attention.

Comment: Was RestKit not converting from the number into a string?

Comment: worse , RestKit throws error at access to variable "_param1" as       "[CFString retain]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x94f8200" in line "[res param1]" or "res.param1". I'd resolved this to change variable type from NSString to NSNumber.Now it works good.